# How to export comments in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, functions, comments, wp-admin, export

I want to export my comments to Excel, PDF or Word. The format really doesn't matter, I just want them exported.

I tried the *Export Comments* plugin, the standard one, but couldn't get it to work, I have to do it manually.

Anyone can suggest something on this topic?

Comment: If you have access to PHPMyAdmin, you could do what [this](http://adminramble.com/export-wordpress-comments-csv-xls-file-format/) page suggests.

Comment: Very helpful!
The idea behind it is that any user on the network as an "Admin" could export. With that I mean that it should be as easy as possible.

Comment: @MikeMadern, this seems not to have been asked before here, would be nice if you assembled an Answer. Not a copy/paste from the link, but one screenshot, a couple of sentences and voilà!

Comment: It wasnt really the answer, what i wanna do is to make it easy for an unedicated user to export comments from wp-admin.

Comment: You can try this simple plugin to [export wordpress comments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/comments-import-export-woocommerce/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1

As the article linked by [@MikeMadern](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80151/how-to-export-comments-in-wordpress/82264#comment109255_80151) suggests:

- in your web host control panel, go to PHPMyAdmin
- select the table `wp_comments`
- select <kbd>Export</kbd>, configure the format

  [image: export mysql]
- further down in the same screen, select the <kbd>Save as file</kbd> and <kbd>Go</kbd>

  [image]

### Option 2

**Or**, as the same article suggests, just use a plugin:

> #### [Export comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/export-comments/)
>
> Pulls comments out of your WordPress database for backups or analysis.

If you have `WP_DEBUG` enabled, the plugin dumps a couple of warnings, but it's nothing critical, and it works as expected.

### Option 3

Just retrieved an old script and adapted to WordPress (using the query from Export Comments as example). Put the file in the root of WP installation and access directly, it will export an Excel file with the comments.

It would be much better to have this as a plugin with security checks and all.
**Remove from server after using**. Or maybe put it in a folder as `index.php` and set an `.htaccess` password.

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( './wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments 
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND ( comment_approved = '1' OR comment_approved = '0' ) 
    ORDER BY comment_ID DESC";

$error = "Error: the query failed...
    <pre style='width:700px;word-wrap:break-word;white-space:normal;'>$query</pre>";

$result = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A ) or wp_die( $error );

$header = array_keys( $result[0] );
$html = array();
$html[] = "<tr><td>" .implode( "</td><td>", $header ) . "</td></tr>";

foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $html[] = "<tr><td>" .implode( "</td><td>", $row ) . "</td></tr>";
}

$html = "<table>" . implode( "\r\n", $html ) . "</table>";

$fileName = 'Comments_' . date("Ymd") . '.xls';
header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" ); 
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName" );

echo $html;
exit();
```

Comment: Im out for something like option 3. Im gonna try and get back to you. Thank you meanwhile.

Comment: Didint get it to work thou. I cant understand why the plugin in firsthand i not working.

Comment: @MeiasSafa, what didn't work? How did you test the code? Any error messages? Was the path to `wp-load.php` correct? What if you disable the `header()` commands?